# CPU bottleneck and Scrypt mining?

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware, mining-setup, scrypt

Im planing to set up a small energy efficient mining rig, im planing to use a low power CPU/MOBO bundle, this is my favorite: Biostar A68I-350 (with 1 DIMM DDR3 4Gb)

It takes only 18W TDP and has one PCI-E 16x for a HD7950. The total Wattage is (considering the usage of a 80+ GOLD PSU) lower than 300< Watt. The KHash/s rate will be 640-650.

How much can the CPU be the cause of a BottleNeck?

Comment: Is this some kind of quest? What's the objective?

Comment: If you want to set a record for a one-card setup, find a card with high ASIC quality - they are good for heavy undervolting. I have one with 88 - works 1010 on 0.95V

Answer (score 1):

The cpu is not used while mining and thus should not bottleneck your setup. The only impact that I could see would be bootup times, and it shouldn't be significant.